# Writing data to existing Xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, win-universal-app

I am developing a universal windows app on windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 and have a pretty large Xml structured like this:

```
<header id = "1">
    <title>
        some text
    </title>
    <question>
        a question
    </question>
    <user_input>
        <input1>
        </input1>
        <input2>
        </input2>
    </user_input>
</header>

<header id = "2">
    <title>
        some text
    </title>
    <question>
        a question
    </question>
    <user_input>
        <input1>
        </input1>
        <input2>
        </input2>
    </user_input>
</header>
...
```

This is repeating many times. There are parts that should never be changed (e.g. title, question). Now i want to write new elements into "ui", so it can be read again and shows the new content in texbox.
I use a FileStream and XmlDocument and XmlNodeList to read the Xml and show the content on textblocks:

```
path = "test.xml";
FileStream stream = new Filestream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAcces.Read);
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(reader);
XmlNodeList node = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("header");
textblock1.Text = node[0].Attributes["id"].Value;
textblock2.Text = node[i].ChildNode[1].InnerText;
....
```

I tried this to write into the Xml:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement ele = xdoc.Element("header");
ele.Add(new XElement("user_input",
        new XElement("input1", newtext)));
        xdoc.Save(path); <---- at this point there is an error
```

"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'"

My question is: how can i write the user input (some string) to the place I want it to be? The first input shall be written into header with id = 1 into user_input, the second into header id = "2" and so on. I already tried to load the xml with XDocument and write a new element with XElement, but it work at all.Is there something wrong with my xml? Or is it the function? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the xml file cannot contain same roots, here you have two `headers` nodes but don't see a root node. So I add a root node for testing your xml file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Topics>
<header id = "1">
...
</header>
</Topics>
```

Secondly, this error

> "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'"

`xdoc.save(string)` is not available in uwp, details you can see the version information of  [XDocument.Save method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830(v=vs.110).aspx).

Thirdly, for this question

> how can i write the user input (some string) to the place I want it to be?

we can insert value to special element by `xpath` or `GetElementsByTagName` method. In uwp, I recommend you use `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom` namespace instead of `System.xml.Ling`.

Here I wrote a demo for insert value to  special place . And upload the demo to GitHub, you can download [CXml](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/tree/master/CXML) for testing.

Mainly Code

```
private async void BtnXmlWrite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String input1value = TxtInput.Text;
    if (null != input1value && "" != input1value)
    {
        var value = doc.CreateTextNode(input1value);
        //find input1 tag in header where id=1
        var xpath = "//header[@id='1']/user_input/input1";
        var input1nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);
        for (uint index = 0; index < input1nodes.Length; index++)
        {
            input1nodes.Item(index).AppendChild(value);
        }
        RichEditBoxSetMsg(ShowXMLResult, doc.GetXml(), true);    
    }
    else
    {
        await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Please type in content in the  box firstly.").ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

More details you can reference [XML dom Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument), [XML and XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp).

Comment: Works fine! Thank you for your effort and the GitHub upload.